# Creating a tree

Tags: modeling

I tryed to create a tree in Blender 2.79, but unfortunately i cannot find **Sampling: Add tree** and **Load Preset** in the toolbar when I open the file I saved before.
Here the screen that appear to me:

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it not an addon? In that case you may have forgotten to save your preferences before closing the preferences window?

Answer (score 2):

It's at the very bottom of the <kbd>T</kbd> bar. It might even be hidden, in which case, you would have a little <kbd>+</kbd> icon to click on:

[image: demo gif]

Note that this menu is available only right after creating the tree. As soon as you do anything else, the tree can't be changed and the menu will be gone.

Comment: Offtopic: What do you use to create gifs?

Comment: Screen to gif or sharex